# running postgres 9.2 & 9.6. in same vm

Tags: postgresql

1. I have installed postgresql 9.2 and 9.6 in centos 7 and created separate service for them. How do I run both versions in same server? They are using the same port.

   When I try to start the 9.2 server its working fine, but when I stop the 9.2 server and start 9.6, I get a warning that postgres client version is 9.2. i have installed 9.6 client but psql is by default taking the older version. How do we resolve this?
2. Will we be able to restore postgresql 9.2 backup in postgresql 9.6? Will there be any data structure level change required to restore 9.2 backup in 9.6? I am completely new to postgresql.

   I have installed postgresql 9.2 and 9.6 in a vm.will normal backup and restore work in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

**Ad 1:**

That will work just fine if you change the port.

Normally all you have to do is to change the `port` setting in the `postgresql.conf` configuration file of the database instance and restart.

**Ad 2:**

You cannot take a dump taken with 9.2 and restore it into 9.6.

Or rather: you can, but there is a good chance that the import will fail or some things will not be restored correctly.

What you have to do is take a dump of the 9.2 database **using `pg_dump` from the 9.6 installation**.

9.6 is aware of the differences to 9.2 and is able to create a dump that can be loaded into 9.6, while 9.2 cannot know what “will be” different in 9.6.